# KitKat Lock Screen: Possible to remove bottom menu?

Tags: lock-screens, nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat, menu

I updated my Nexus 4 to KitKat. It adds a menu bar at the bottom of the lock screen. By default, it shows the camera on the right hand side and caret in the middle.

Is it possible to remove the bottom menu bar from the lock screen? Alternatively, is it possible to remove the icons on the menu bar.

Comment: Are you sure its configurable?

Comment: Nope, that's why I'm asking. I'll rephrase to make that clearer.